# What permission does Android GC use

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

Recently I read some articles about CVE-2014-7911, the exploit [PoC](https://github.com/retme7/CVE-2014-7911_poc/blob/master/cve20147911/src/c/v/e/MainActivity.java) create a instance of the BinderProxy class anyway with the deserialized values of the object and send it to system_server. When GC deals with it, the PoC will be called with system permission ( The permission that system_server has )

However, when I tried to send a normal Serializable class to system_server use the way same with the PoC, the code in my own finalize() method which requires system permission will not be executed.

The question is: **Why couldn't my code get system permission when being GC?**

This is my Java code:

```
public class Seria implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0;

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("gc-permission");
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        destroy();
    }

    private native void destroy();
}
```

And my C code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_android_study_gcpremission_Seria_destroy(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {

    // TODO
    int a = -1;
    a = system("echo 'a' > /sdcard/test/b.txt"); // normal premission
    a = system("echo 'a' > /data/b.txt"); // need system permission
    a = system("chmod 777 /data/b.txt"); // need system permission
}
```

Comment: Why do you think your code *would* get system permission when being garbage collected?

Comment: Well, I just don't have idea about that, thanks a lot, I'll read some articles about Android GC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why couldn't my code get system permission when being GC?

Your class doesn't exist in system-server, so when system-server goes to deserialize your class it just throws a ClassNotFoundException and nothing happens. The exploit relies on using a class that already exists in system-server.

Comment: @KailNethunter Also note that you don't need to use JNI or finalize for this - **if** you could just send any class you wanted to system-server, then you could just write a class with a `readObject` method that will run with system permission.